# 20,000,000 table joining on itself too slow

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, mariadb

I have a table (variable (unlimited variety), attr (exactly 3 different attributes), date, state (can only be 0, 1, or 2) ):

```
     PK       PK      PK
 ------------------------------------
| Variable | Attr |   Date   | State |
|------------------------------------|
|    V1    |  A1  |01/01/14  |  0    |      
|    V1    |  A1  |01/02/14  |  2    |           
|    V1    |  A1  |01/03/14  |  1    |     
|    V1    |  A1  |01/04/14  |  2    |      
|    V1    |  A2  |01/01/14  |  1    |      
|    V1    |  A2  |01/02/14  |  0    |           
|    V1    |  A2  |01/03/14  |  1    |     
|    V1    |  A2  |01/04/14  |  1    |  
|    V1    |  A3  |01/01/14  |  0    |      
|    V1    |  A3  |01/02/14  |  0    |           
|    V1    |  A3  |01/03/14  |  1    |     
|    V1    |  A3  |01/04/14  |  2    |  
|    V2    |  A1  |01/01/14  |  2    |      
|    V2    |  A1  |01/02/14  |  1    |           
|    V2    |  A1  |01/03/14  |  2    |     
|    V2    |  A1  |01/04/14  |  1    |      
|    V2    |  A2  |01/01/14  |  1    |      
|    V2    |  A2  |01/02/14  |  2    |           
|    V2    |  A2  |01/03/14  |  1    |     
|    V2    |  A2  |01/04/14  |  0    |  
|    V2    |  A3  |01/01/14  |  1    |      
|    V2    |  A3  |01/02/14  |  0    |           
|    V2    |  A3  |01/03/14  |  2    |     
|    V2    |  A3  |01/04/14  |  1    |  
|    V3    |  A1  |01/01/14  |  1    |      
|    V3    |  A1  |01/02/14  |  2    |           
|    V3    |  A1  |01/03/14  |  1    |     
|    V3    |  A1  |01/04/14  |  1    |      
|    V3    |  A2  |01/01/14  |  1    |      
|    V3    |  A2  |01/02/14  |  0    |           
|    V3    |  A2  |01/03/14  |  0    |     
|    V3    |  A2  |01/04/14  |  2    |  
|    V3    |  A3  |01/01/14  |  1    |      
|    V3    |  A3  |01/02/14  |  0    |           
|    V3    |  A3  |01/03/14  |  2    |     
|    V1    |  A3  |01/04/14  |  1    | 
|    .     |  .   |.         |  .    |
|    Vn    |  An  |n         |  n    | 
|----------|------|----------|-------|
```

I will be running this query to get the results I need:

```
select
    bases.variable as basis_v,
    bases.attr as basis_a,
    bases.state as basis_s,
    counts.variable,
    counts.attr,
    counts.state,
    count(*) as count
from 
    mytable bases
        inner join
    mytable counts
        on bases.date = counts.date
group by
    bases.variable,
    bases.attr,
    bases.state,
    counts.variable,
    counts.attr,
    counts.state
order by
    bases.variable,
    bases.attr,
    bases.state,
    counts.variable,
    counts.attr,
    counts.state;
```

The table (innodb), which contains about 20,000,000 rows is joining on itself (20,000,000 x 20,000,000). I have a 6 core Intel i7-430k, 16GB ram, 128GB SSD system which is barley being utilized. I ran this query for 24 hours and stopped it because it was still not finished. One of my biggest concerns is only about 1Gb of ram was being used and my cpu was topping out at about 10% and my SSD was about 1% usage on average even though my configurations allow for the buffer to access 12GB. I understand MySQL 5.6 is single threaded so I am trying to make modifications. So far it is very slow and I want to obtain the results faster. I am thinking about partitioning the table into 16 partitions using the 'variable' column. There are 2 indexes PRIMARY=Variable + attr + date and another on DATE. Besides the partition change I can't find any other changes which will help increase the speed and I fear partitioning alone will not help significantly enough. Ideally I would like this query to finish in 2-5 hours. Any ideas on how to increase the speed of this query would help. The table also is never used for write operations except at first to just load the data.

The first thing I want to do is to choose a variable + attr + state combination which I want to base my query off of. So lets say I choose V2 + A3 + 2. Next I want to go and find the dates of all rows where var = V2, attr = A3, and state = 2. Next I need to go through each of these dates and count all the other var + attr + state combinations. For example if V2 + A3 + 2 occurs on 01/01/14, 02/06/14, 02/07/14, 04/09/14, and 05/03/14 it would go through all the other variables on these dates and add up the occurrences for each var + attr + state combination. So the output would group each var + attr + state combination and the count for each of these combinations would show. The query I provided
returns counts for the variable + attribute + state combination I chose. So this is just for one combination, but I would like to get counts for the possible combinations (~20,000 different variables x 6 different attributes x 3 different states). 
[JFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/63033/2)

Side Note: I have looked possibly into doing this using Hadoop but I would like to stick with MySQL if I can. Also, I noticed there is another database called MariaDB which is a fork of MySQL which seems to do multi-threading automatically, is this true? Is this a possible quick solution? I have read about shard-query which allows the use of multiple cores, has anybody had experience with this, would it help with my query?

Comment: What's the purpose of this massive cross-join?

Comment: for every variable + attr + state combination I want to get a count  of how many ocurrences of all other individual variable + attr + state combinations occurred on that day

Comment: How many variable/attribute/state combinations do you have?

Comment: about ~20,000 variables x 6 attributes x 3 states x ~60 days = ~20,000,000. So about 360,000 combinations x ~60 days of data

Comment: Try it out on a smaller dataset, for me the query does not return what you described.

Comment: What does EXPLAIN give you? What happens performance-wise if you restrict your date range to one day or a range of a few days?

Comment: I updated the original to better explain what I am trying to do and provided a jFiddle link.

Comment: @Kombajnzbożowy . . . The query returns the number of times that pairs of variable/attr/status appear together on a single day in the data.

Comment: yes, and then the aggragate function count sums up all the occurrences

Comment: Are you sure the table is cross joining the records (20,000,000 x 20,000,000)? It shouldn't. The query looks for all pairs that occur in a day and then counts how many days that combination occurs. (And this is what you want it to do, yes?) So it still *is* an inner join and the number of records get only multiplied with the avarage number of records per day. So say you have 10,000 records per day, then you get 20,000,000 x 10,000 - which is still a lot to do aggregations on. And sorry, I don't see any way to improve this.

Comment: Some more information like table definition (including indexes) and output of explain and/or explain extended would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see that hadoop is necessarily going to help very much.  Your only partitioning key is the date, and the fundamental issue is the looping by day.  Hadoop will help, but you might do almost as well with the following approach:

1. Add a date index onto the table;
2. Read the data in *one day at a time* into your favorite application language (java, python, whatever).
3. Find all pairs in the application using a nested loop, saving the counts in some big array.
4. Repeat and update the counts for each day.

Even this may not be tractible.  If you have 20,000,000 rows and 1,000 days of data, then you have 20,000 rows for each day.  That is 20,000 * 20,000 combinations for a single day . . . 400,000,000.  However, if peak days have 100,000 instead, then you have 10,000,000,000 combinations just for that day.  This is a lot of intermediate results to process, whether a database or hadoop.

Note:  the way the problem is specified (equality by day), it is hard to parallelize the problem for a single day.  It is possible, but that would require much more work.

EDIT:

This is a classic problem of finding combinations, which is the first step in any association rule (aka market basket analysis) problem.  The normal first step is to filter the possible items (in your case a triplet of three columns) based on frequency.  So, start with a query that does:

```
select cnt, count(*)
from (select variable as basis_v, attr as basis_a, state as basis_s, count(*) as cnt
      from mytable
      group by variable, attr, state
     ) vas
group by cnt
order by 1 desc;
```

This will give you an idea of a "support" cutoff.  Say it is 20.  Then create a temporary table, `SupportItems`, with the combinations that appear on at least 20 days.  Now you problem is to find combinations among these.  Then use this table for filtering the items in your data before you do the `group by`.

Comment: I would have 20,000 variables x 6 attributes x 3 states of rows per day (360,000). In total I would have 360,000 x ~60 days  = ~ 20,000,000 rows. Also, would java really help that much in speed?

Comment: @user2924127 . . . No.  The number of combinations that you want to process on a given day is really, really big, and you have no filtering.  This is not a hard problem, just computationally really expensive.  It is unclear to me why you would want all possible pairs.  You wouldn't even be able to look at the results.  (By comparison, a typical grocery store stocks 20,000-30,000 items and a wholesaler, such as Costco, a few thousand.)

Comment: I will have a "HAVING" command after to display only counts that are very high, but I need to know which combinations have a high 'count' so I must go through all of them to find out. From the query, only about 0.001% of the rows will show after the having command.

Comment: @user2924127 . . . I figured as much.  To solve this problem, you need to do some filtering *before* the join rather than after.

Comment: Yes I wish I could, but I need to check all the combinations. I am thinking I can use Java and your approach you suggested but create say 12 threads (I have a 6 core processor) and give them each 5 or so days and they could update the counts into one very large share-able hashmap or something. I would ideally really like to stick with MySQL (or any other database) though by finding a way to utilize the hardware better. I realize it is a large amount of combinations to go through, but I think if I could somehow use 100% of my resources I could get the results within a few hours.

Comment: MySQL clearly doesn't try to optimize nested loop joins (the method for doing the cross join).  This wouldn't be a priority in terms of optimization because this is very much on the edge of using databases efficiently, so it is possible that no mainstream databases would do this in parallel.  On the other hand, equi-joins are very highly optimized in many databases.

Comment: Gordon Linoff - I have just read about shard-query which allows multiple core use. I was wondering if you had any experience with it before as it seems quite popular?

Comment: Gordon Linoff - I just read the EDIT you posted. How would I know 'the combinations that appear on at least 20 days?'

Comment: @user2924127 . . . That is what the query in the edited part does.  As for shards, that is a type of parallelism similar to partitioning large tables.

Comment: Sorry I am very confused. I ran the query and received a cnt of relativley low numbers (1 to 90) while count(*) had high numbers from (1-5000+). I am not sure now what to do with that

Answer (score 0):

The following approach is tricky, but if the date range is relatively small (60 distinct dates) and known to you in advance, you may try:

```
select v1.variable as basis_v, v1.attr as basis_a, v1.state as basis_s,
       v2.variable, v2.attr, v2.state,
       bit_count(v1.encoded_dates & v2.encoded_dates)
  from (select variable, attr, state,
               max(case when date = '2014-01-01' then 1 else 0 end) +
               max(case when date = '2014-01-02' then 2 else 0 end) +
               max(case when date = '2014-01-03' then 4 else 0 end) +
               max(case when date = '2014-01-04' then 8 else 0 end) +
               ... as encoded_dates
          from mytable
         group by variable, attr, state) v1
  join (select variable, attr, state,
               max(case when date = '2014-01-01' then 1 else 0 end) +
               max(case when date = '2014-01-02' then 2 else 0 end) +
               max(case when date = '2014-01-03' then 4 else 0 end) +
               max(case when date = '2014-01-04' then 8 else 0 end) +
               ... as encoded_dates
          from mytable
         group by variable, attr, state) v2
 where v1.encoded_dates & v2.encoded_dates > 0
 order by v1.variable, v1.attr, v1.state,
          v2.variable, v2.attr, v2.state;
```

What does it do? It aggregates first all  triplets encoding dates when they appear in an integer, where each bit represents a date. Then it performs a self-join with bit AND on the encoded dates, finally counts the bits.

I'm not 100% sure this will be more efficient, but I hope pre-aggregation will cut the cost of the expensive cross join by date on original table. If you can, extract the inner queries into a temporary table.

Here's your fiddle showing the query result is equivalent to original one: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7b749/10

Comment: Hi tried this, but it shows no improvement. I have been running it for about 6 hours now and it is still going. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Have you also tried with materializing the aggregation?

Answer (score 0):

try the following query:

```
select
    bases.variable as basis_v,
    bases.attr as basis_a,
    bases.state as basis_s,
    counts.variable,
    counts.attr,
    counts.state,count(bases.variable) over(partition by     bases.attr,
    bases.state,
    counts.variable,
    counts.attr,
    counts.state)
 from 
    mytable bases
        inner join
    mytable counts
        on bases.date = counts.date
 order by
    bases.variable,
    bases.attr,
    bases.state,
    counts.variable,
    counts.attr,
    counts.state;
```

Comment: I get a syntax error underline under the partition by but can't find the issue